# bootstrap scrollspy doesn t work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am begginer with bootstrap. I'm trying create the ScrollSpy Bootstrap on my page but it doesn't work. Whatever I do it doesnt work properly and I have no idea why? Could somebody look at my code and tell what is wrong. Here it is:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <style>
    #top-center-photo{
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    #aboutus-content{
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: green;
    }

    #offert{
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body  data-spy="scroll"  data-target=".navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#top-center-photo">o nas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#aboutus-content">oferta</a></li>
            <li><a href="#offert">realizacje</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </nav>
<div id="top-center-photo">
</div>

<div id="aboutus-content">
</div>

<div id="offert">
</div>

<div id="realizacje">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please tell clearly?

Comment: Hi dendi, I checked your code in browser, its working fine.. what do you want exactly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only problem is that you have not linked js file properly

put this code above `</body>` tag

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript --><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is your scroll-spy: [Demo](http://codepen.io/Sykox/pen/pyzBQM) working fine

There are no errors in your code... its working fine :)